# installing juju client on windows 8.1

Tags: juju

Not sure if I am missing something pretty simple here but when I download the juju Windows client and I try run it all I get is "This app cannot run on your PC". It seems that it should be a straight forward install but I do not seem to be able to get past this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the installer in compatibility mode with Windows 7?

Comment: Yes I did Marco. I also tried to run it as an administrator and I get the message that "windows cannot find c:\downloads\juju-setup1.16.6-signed.exe' Make sure you have type the name correctly, then try again." Which of course is ridiculous because I am right clicking the file and selecting run as administrator.

Comment: I filed a bug on this, let's continue the discussion there, thanks! https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1294198